# how to print the list of strings from the arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

I need some help with my code, I'm stored the list of strings in arrays and when I try to print the list of strings, it would not let me to print them when I use the variables in the loop.

```
pos_start = list()
pos_top = list()
pos_width = list()
pos_height = list()
prog_title = list()

for ind, row in enumerate(programs):
    programs_top = 315
    program_height = 33
    program_gap = 3
    position_start = start_pos
    position_top = programs_top + channel_index * (program_height + program_gap + 1.5)

    #create width size for per program button
    if program_length >= 10 and program_length <= 45:  #30 mins
        program_width = 342

    pos_start.append(position_start)
    pos_top.append(position_top)
    pos_width.append(program_width)
    pos_height.append(program_height)
position_start = map(str, pos_start)
position_top = map(str, pos_top)
program_width = map(str, pos_width)
program_height = map(str, pos_height)
program_title = map(str, prog_title)

for position_start, position_width, position_height, program_title in zip(pos_start, pos_width, pos_height, prog_title):
    print position_start
```

Here is the output for position_start:

```
13:41:23 T:4812  NOTICE: ['375', '1073', '1771', '2120', '2469', '2818', '3167', '3516', 
'3865', '4563', '5261', '5959', '6657', '7355', '7704', '8053', '8402', '8751', '9100', '9449', 
'9798', '10147', '10496', '10845', '11543', '12241', '12939', '13288', '13637', '13986', '14335',
'15033', '15731', '16080', '16429', '16778', '17127', '17476', '17825', '18174', '18523', '18872', 
'19221', '19570', '19919', '20268', '20617', '20966', '21315', '21664', '22013', '22362', '22711', 
'23060', '23409', '23758', '24107', '24456', '24805', '25154', '25503', '25852', '26201', '26550', 
'26899', '27248', '27597', '28295', '28993']
```

I can be able to use the `print position_start` outside the for loop.

Can you please tell me how I can print each string that I want to read the strings from the arrays?

I try to use `for position_start, position_width, position_height, program_title in zip(pos_start, pos_width, pos_height, prog_title):` to print each string but it won't let me.

Any idea?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for item in position_start:
    print item
```

If they are all the same length (and I don't recommend parallel arrays as it is very easy for them to be one item off) you could do something like:

```
for i in range(0, len(position_start)):
    print position_start[i]
    print position_top[i]
    print program_width[i]
    print program_heigh[i]
    print program_title[i]
```

You could also zip them like you were trying to do to get a list of tuples. This will work for even or uneven lists. Here is an example:

```
import itertools
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = [4, 5, 6, 7]
listZipped = itertools.izip_longest(l1, l2)

for item in listZipped:
    print item
```

Comment: what about the other variables `position_top`, `program_width`, 
`program_height` and `program_title`? how i can read the list of strings?

Comment: My answer should now be sufficent @Rob

Comment: thank you very much for this, can I use `for item1, item2, item3, item4, item5 in position_start, position_top, program_width, program_height, program_title:` to print the list of string for each variable?

Comment: That would be bad as there would need to be an `item` in your for loop for each item in the list. For example if my lists both have 3 items, i would need: `for item1, item2, item3 in l1, l2:` for it to unpack all the values

Comment: And that would only work if the lists had the same number of items

Comment: can you show me an example how I can use something is like this? `for item1, item2, item3, item4, item5 in position_start, position_top, program_width, program_height, program_title:`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76708/discussion-between-heinst-and-rob).

Comment: @Rob please check the chat. I explained more as to why you can't do what you want to do

Comment: When I try this: `for position_start, position_width, position_height, program_title in zip(pos_start, pos_width, pos_height, prog_title): print position_start` it will print one element from the list where i have more than one. how i can unpack the list of elements using the loop that i created?